# IOS / Android push notification content alignment

Tags: php, android, ios, push-notification

I have an PHP script that send push notification to IOS and Android device.
Now my problem is that when is send the notification in English then OS show the notification content from Left To Right that is fine. But When I send the notification message in arabic then Notification must be shown from right to left. I don't know that how I can achieve this task. Is there any solution via PHP?

Comment: Anyway, you have to change in the android/iOS Code set.